# flow of json to tableview

Tags: ios, json, tableview

i have another problem this time, i'm fetching json codes that will be used to populate the tableview i have in my xib so, to start with my .h file

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ASIHTTPRequestDelegate> {
NSMutableArray *resultArray;
IBOutlet UITableView *thetableView;
NSMutableData *responseData;
```

}

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *arrayTypes;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *resultArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *thetableView;
```

in my .m file i implemented this

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
responseData = [[NSMutableData data]retain];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/fetch.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];    
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.thetableView reloadData];
}
```

in the connectiondidfinishloading:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[connection release];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData release];
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
NSDictionary *dictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
NSMutableArray *response = [dictionary valueForKey:@"itemn"];
 resultArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:response];
```

}

and now the problem, the tableview has implemented both the numberofrowsinsection and didselectrowatindextpath methods but the latter is never called as the size of the array is 0 and even reloading, it doesn't work am i missing something or is there a similar tutorial to follow? sorry for the length just hoping the infos will be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should reload tableview once you have the complete data..see the updated code

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[connection release];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData release];
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
NSDictionary *dictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
NSMutableArray *response = [dictionary valueForKey:@"itemn"];
 resultArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:response];

//Reload your table with data..
[self.thetableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: OMG! IT WORKED! Silly me should have tried that and tried more! THANX!